# I want to take a syslog file 3 by 3 lines

Tags: php, file, drupal, rsyslog

All i want is to open a rsyslog file with `fopen()` take the first 3 lines set a variable with the last of this 3 lines. Then take the other 3 lines e.t.c.

```
 $path_file = variable_get('$path');
 $file = fopen($path_file, 'r');
 for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
   $line = fgets($file);
   $line = variable_set($line);
 }
 fclose($file);
```

Comment: I posted some really wrong code!

Comment: what is your problem. do you get any error ? or what ? please clarify you question.

Comment: I want to take the first 3 lines and then close the file. Then when the function runs again take the next 3 and close again the file. e.t.c

Comment: If you want to get the next 3 lines, you need to save the line number you ended at each time, so you know where to start reading.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file()` instead (reads everything in as an array)

Try this:

```
$file = file('$path'); 

for($x = 0; $x < count($file); $x = $x + 3) 
{
   if(isset($file[$x]) && isset($file[$x +1]) && isset($file[$x + 2]) 
   {
      //do something with the values. 
   } 
} 


function readFileStartingAtLineNumber($x) 
{
    $file = file('$path'); 

    if(isset($file[$x]) && isset($file[$x +1]) && isset($file[$x + 2]) 
    {
      //do something with the values. 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I want to take the first 3 lines and then close the file. Then when the function runs again take the next 3 and close again the file. e.t.c

Comment: Ahh, i thought you wanted it split the values in categories of 3.Then just do $file[0], $file[1] and $file[2] if you are sure the lines are not empty.

Comment: and how i will read the 4th,5th,6th line the second time the function takes place?

Comment: because maybe i want this 3 lines some other time not all the values in one

Comment: Sorry, then i misunderstood you compteley. Does that method help?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLog($path, $numberOfLines, $lastIndex) {
    $file = fopen($path, 'r');
    if (!$file) {
        print 'error opening file';
    }
    else {
        $data   = '';
        $i      = -1;
        while(($line = fgets($file)) !== FALSE) {
            if(++$i < $lastIndex)       continue;
            if($numberOfLines-- == 0)   break;
            $data .= $line;
        }
        fclose($file);
        if ($data === '') {
            print 'EOF reached without getting data';
        }
    }
    return $i;  
}
```

Comment: as lastindex what i must set? the data?

Comment: the last insdex reached and returned by getLog()

Comment: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given